# How to sort nested_attributes in params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I am trying to post nested_attributes params from JavaScript something like,

> Parameters: {"product"=>{"answers_attributes"=>{"1"=>{"contents"=>"Spring",
>   "questionnaire_id"=>"8"}, "3"=>{"questionnaire_id"=>"10",
>   "contents"=>{"0"=>"PC"}, "etc"=>""}, "0"=>{"contents"=>"Aa",
>   "questionnaire_id"=>"7"}, "2"=>{"questionnaire_id"=>"9",
>   "contents"=>"Ski"}}, "sub"=>"0", "lang"=>"en"}, "auth_token"=>"xxxxx"}

But the order of 'answers_attributes' is 1,3,0,2 in this case.
In rails3, the answers record are created in this order.
I want to sort the answers_attributes params from 1,3,0,2 to 0,1,2,3 in server side(rails).

I know parms["product"]["answers_attributes"].sort can sort the order, but params are not changed.
How do I rebuild params by sorted answers_attributes ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple,

Suppose your `params` is

```
params = {"product"=>{"answers_attributes"=>{
"1"=>{"contents"=>"Spring", "questionnaire_id"=>"8"}, 
"3"=>{"questionnaire_id"=>"10", "contents"=>{"0"=>"PC"}, "etc"=>""} ,
"0"=>{"contents"=>"Aa", "questionnaire_id"=>"7"}, 
"2"=>{"questionnaire_id"=>"9", "contents"=>"Ski"}}, "sub"=>"0", "lang"=>"en"} ,
"auth_token"=>"xxxxx"}
```

Then just do

```
params['product']['answers_attributes'].sort
```

#### update : To rebuild the params with sorted answers

```
params[:product][:answers_attributes] = Hash[*params[:product][:answers_attributes].sort.flatten]
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, yes i know .sort, I want to rebuild params by sorted answers_attributes. Any ideas ?

Comment: Both didn't work fine. params is HashWithIndifferentAccess class. It couldn't do sort! and the method 'params[:product][:answers_attributes] =' assigns Array class.

Comment: I did it! params[:product][:answers_attributes] = Hash[*params[:product][:answers_attributes].sort.flatten] works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yup, you are right .. sorry to provide you untested answer. Thanks for pointing it out.